# Powershell: sorting directories based on file count

Tags: powershell, shell-script, sorting

I am attempting to create a list that counts the number of files in a folder and then sorts the order of the folders based on that count. I have the following but it doesn't work (i.e. doesn't sort):

```
Get-Childitem -Directory | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $folderList=$_.Name
        $fileListInFolder=(Get-Childitem -file -Path $_)
        $fileCountInFolder=@()
        $fileCountInFolder+=("{0:d2}" -f $fileListInFolder.count)
        $arrayOfFileCountInFolder=(Write-Output $fileCountInFolder" "$folderList)
        $arrayOfFileCountInFolder | Sort-Object
    }
```

This script produces a list like the one below (the first digits represent file count and the remainders of the string is the directory):

```
41 02 F OR 12K48b
21 03 F CC 12K48b
05 05 F OR 12K48b
21 06 B OR 06K64b
```

I am getting a list of what I desire but it will not sort. What am I missing?

P.S. If I were to manually enter those strings into an array, sorting would work. For instance:

```
$array=@("41 02 F OR 12K48b","21 03 F CC 12K48b","05 05 F OR 12K48b","21 06 B OR 06K64b")

$array | Sort-Object
```

results in:

```
05 05 F OR 12K48b
21 03 F CC 12K48b
21 06 B OR 06K64b
41 02 F OR 12K48b
```

Comment: Hard to make out what's what in your desired results without seeing the sample data. But I'm curious as to why you're putting all your info into one string per directory instead of creating a custom object where properties like size and count can be mumerical properties that can yield summary data and the output piped to a girdview control where you can sort and filter with ease...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not sorting as you are immediately sending the count of each folder to `Sort-Object`. Try sending the result after you have collected/counted the files. Move the `Foreach-Object`'s closing bracket before the pipe symbol, then sort.

```
Get-Childitem -Directory | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $folderList=$_.Name
        $fileListInFolder=(Get-Childitem -file -Path $_)
        $fileCountInFolder=@()
        $fileCountInFolder+=("{0:d2}" -f $fileListInFolder.count)
        $arrayOfFileCountInFolder=(Write-Output $fileCountInFolder" "$folderList)
        $arrayOfFileCountInFolder} | Sort-Object
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.